# What is the max number of passengers Batman could carry in a single Bat-vehicle?

Tags: dc, batman

I'm trying to think of one of Batman's bat[vehicle] that could hold multiple people.  Most seem to be single-occupant methods of transportation, like the Batcycle and Batmobile.  Occasionally, there would be room for a single passenger (namely Robin), like in the Batcopter.

Are there any Batman vehicles that can hold more than 2 people?  How many passengers could fit in a single vehicle?

*Note, I'd like to restrict it to Batman vehicles, so avoiding random things driven by Bruce Wayne.  Preferably, there's something that matches the Bat______ format.

Comment: I guess he could carry several Penguins, pan intended!

Comment: Comics-wise or all-scope wise? (cartoons, movies etc) (I might be wrong but I think I remember the _Arkham_ games' Batmobile having back seats - or was that _Telltales_?)

Comment: @Jenayah All scope.  Yes the Arkham Knight Batmobile had a couple seats in the trunk.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that, under "clown car" rules, he could fit an unlimited number of Joker clones.

Comment: The Batwing takes Batman, Robin, Alfred, and Barbara Gordon (and a bunch of gremlins, but they're on the outside) in the Lego movie

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was reasonably comprehensive. Is there anything you think I should add before you'd consider an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum apparently I forgot to accept.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [**Bat-train**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Bat-Train) appears in [Batman Vol.1 #95](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_95)

It's a standard locomotive of its era and had five passenger cars as well as two flat-cars for storing the batplane and batmobile. There would be comfortable space for 450 passengers seated and standing or you could [crush-load](https://schott.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/04/08/super-dense-crushload/) over two thousand passengers if you removed the seating.

[image: A Train with a black locomotive engine drawing carriages behind. The train has a cow-catcher front, with a batman like visage. A red car drives beside the train, with exposition about how they are following it to intercept batman.]

[image: Figures walking along the top of the Bat Train carriages. Batman is in pursuit, and they are declaring their intent to shoot him.]

---

We're introduced to the **Bat-Truck** in the recent [Batman Vol.2 #42](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_2_42)

This truck is mostly storage space and appears to be about the size of a [double-width, extra-long shipping container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermodal_container#60-foot_containers) which means it could carry at least a hundred and fifty people in relative comfort (approx 2ft of space between each person) or nearly 400 if crush-loaded.

[image: A large black, sleek truck in a tunnel like warehouse. The front bumper of the truck is the height of an adult human. The front windscreen of the is shiny and black. The yellow batman symbol is on the side of the cab.]

---

The **[Flying Bat-Cave](http://dcuguide.com/w/Flying_Bat-Cave)** first appears in [Detective Comics #186](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_186).

It appears to have ample space for at least 30-50 passengers and maybe more, depending on its maximum take-off weight.

[image: A large helicopter flies over city of gotham. It is hemispherical. An inset picture exposes the fact that batman cannot set foot in gotham. In the opposing panel Batman instructs Robin to enter a spherical object, the Bat-o-sphere, that will take them underwater.]

---

The two original Batmobiles were a 1939 Cadillac Fleetwood 75 (complete with drop-down seating for four passengers) seen in the 1942 serial movie [Batman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0035665/)

[image: Black and white period photo of the 1939 Cadillac Fleetwood 75]
[image: A colour close up photo of the 1939 Cadillac Fleetwood 75, showing the back seat with the base of the seat hinged so it can swing up and out of the way]

and a 1949 Mercury 2 Door Coupe (used in the 15-part serial [*New Adventures of Batman and Robin, the Boy Wonder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_and_Robin_(serial)) capable of seating six in comfort.

[image: Black and white photo of batman next to the 1949 Mercury 2 Door Coupe]
[image: A colour magazine advert for the 1949 Mercury 2 Door Coupe, listing it as seating 6 people.]

Comment: And no, this doesn't even break into the top 50 stupidest things ever seen in Batman.

Comment: Bonus points for Design, malus points for Sneak

Comment: Excellent example.  I was using [this list](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Vehicles) to try and find something, but it's missing a lot.

Comment: "appears to be about the size of a standard shipping container" The width of a standard shipping container is 8 feet: http://www.containeralliance.com/specifications.php That is much larger.

Comment: @Acccumulation - That's a fair point. It looks to be approx 150% the width of a standard container and at least 53 feet long. I've redone my maths.

Comment: This is just gonna go on the pile of things committed to ink that I'm going to ignore about batman.

Comment: @Sidney - https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/8/89742/3064835-batmanhumanfish.jpg

Comment: The Lego Batman Movie also shows the train... as well as a Bat Space Shuttle and a Bat version of a C-130 cargo plane.  Probably not canon tho?

Comment: @JPhi1618 - Lego canon is canon to Lego

Comment: Unless that guy in the blue coveralls is very short, that bumper has to be well over 20' wide.  Not sure what the truck is for, but it's not going to drive down US roadways.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - The cow-catcher on the front is to encourage other road users out of the way

Comment: @Acccumulation, the length of out-stretched arms is generally 6-7 feet (2 meters) from tip to tip.  This truck is about 5 time the size of the person leaning on it or 30 feet (10 meters), what road will holds this truck?

Comment: [...Welp.](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/216/380/023.jpg)

Comment: @Valorum Of course, that Bat tow truck is eminently practical...

Answer (score 10):

There is a scene in the 2017 movie "Batman and Harley Quinn" where Batman, Nightwing, and Harley Quinn are riding together in the batmobile.

Comment: "It's not so bad. It smells like... discipline."  Eesh... what an awkward attempt by the writer at inserting self-parody. (I could imagine that line as words put in his mouth in a flashback as retold by Harley, but otherwise, it's just jarringly out of character.) The cliched, dragged-out fart gag is also kinda lame. I loved B:TAS, but from this sample (and from other mentions I've seen of it), it's probably just as well that I skipped this recent sequel.

Comment: It also has three seats in Batman: Arkham Knight; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnWGWo4CGWQ

Comment: I don't go for fart jokes either, but this movie was an awful lot of fun. The next five minutes (after the lame fart gags) are worth the price of admission all on their own.

Comment: Why are people upvoting an answer that says 3 people can fit in the Batmobile on a question about the maximum passengers in any Bat-vehicle? It is obviously wrong.

Comment: @jpmc26 "*... on a question about the maximum passengers in any Bat-vehicle?*" - the actual question asked was: "***Are there any Batman vehicles that can hold more than 2 people?***", hence my answer is valid, if albeit on the small side. And I'm pretty sure I've seen videos where the BatMobile has held 4 passengers, but I don't recall specific examples at the moment.

Comment: The title clearly states, "What is the max number of passengers Batman could carry in a single Bat-vehicle?" The subquestion you mention is only indicating that the asker is unsure a larger vehicle exists. It is not what's being asked.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I think that *any* mention of a bat-vehicle that can hold more than 2 people is fair game for an answer. I've probably picked the three largest, but there's plenty of scope for smaller vehicles to be recognised, hence why I've mentioned the batmobiles from the 1942 and 1949 films.

Comment: @Valorum That would make it a list question, closable as Too Broad, wouldn't it?

Comment: @jpmc26 - You could try it, I suppose

Answer (score 5):

***H.M.S. Batboat*** appeared in *[Detective Comics Vol.1 #110](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_110)*, when Batman was visiting London.

On the cover we see at least four people on board (there's a sailor visible through the front window), and room for plenty more if needed.

[image]

[image]

Images kindly provided by [Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum).

Comment: Ahoy there. Have an upvote